# Keep Camera Flash On When Screen Off

Tags: android

I have this code to turn camera flash on and off in android:

```
 params = camera.getParameters();
 params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
 camera.setParameters(params);
 camera.startPreview();
 isFlashOn = true;
```

The problem appear if flash is on and user turn off screen. flash automatically turned off and return on when screen is on.

I need to keep flash on when screen off.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174309/1316483) to the problem you're having. "The key is changing the state back to `FLASH_MODE_OFF` and then back to `FLASH_MODE_TORCH`."

In the solution, he creates a `Timer Task` to handle checking if the screen is on or not. He then turns off the flash and then back on.

Down below the linked solution is another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21114797/1316483) which added a `thread` and made it go to sleep for 200 milliseconds before sending the `torch` command.

So I'd say the solution you're looking for is the combination of both solutions.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // assume we start with screen on and save that state ;-)
    this.pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    screenOn = this.pm.isScreenOn();

    // program a timer which checks if the light needs to be re-activated
    this.mTimer = new Timer();
    this.mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // re-activate the LED if screen turned off
            if(!pm.isScreenOn() && pm.isScreenOn() != screenOn) {
                Log.i("SleepLEDservice", "re-activated the LED");
                // really it's NOT ENOUGH to just "turn it on", i double-checked this
                setFlashlight(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setFlashlight(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            }
            screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();                 
        }
    };
}

private void setFlashlight(String newMode) {
    try {
        this.frontCamPara = this.frontCam.getParameters();
        if(this.frontCamPara.getFlashMode() != newMode) {
            this.frontCamPara.setFlashMode(newMode);
            this.frontCam.setParameters(frontCamPara);  
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Again, credit should go to @stefanjunker and @BlueJam as their answers are referenced in this.